# Swift version manager

Tags: swift, xcode, rive

I have a .rive file which I want to use in my Xcode project. So I added pod 'RiveRuntime'.

I installed. But while importing the pod import RiveRuntime
I'm getting an error :Failed to build module 'RiveRuntime'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.6 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.62 clang-1316.0.20.8)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

How can I handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you compile the SDK with 5.7.2 from source

Comment: Thank you, but can you please help to find a way to compile SDK with 5.7.2 from source